# Word for something that may be a problem in the future

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a single word that can be used to describe a situation/course of action which currently causes no problems but may cause issues in the future.

Comment: First of all, I doubt you'll find a word that applies to both a situation *and* to a course of action. Second, is it *known* that a problem might occur in the future?

Comment: You must include a suitable sentence using the word as an example.

Comment: Example sentence please. The primary reason for this is so we know whether you're looking for a noun or an adjective.

Comment: It was to use as a one word comment in a program. Example
# <word> This might result in bad values in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Risk / risky**, from [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/risk):

> **1** A situation involving exposure to danger.
>         **1.1** *[in singular]* The possibility that something unpleasant or unwelcome will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Liability. Both in the financial sense and in the metaphorical sense. A person may be referred to as a liability if they pose a potential risk in the future.

> 2.usually in singular A person or thing whose presence or behaviour is likely to put one at a disadvantage. 
> [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/liability)

Note, many dictionaries will only list liability in the sense of legal obligation. I think the word is commonly understood to mean anything which may potentially become an encumbrance or burden or nuisance.

> ‘Now that we have seen his response to the revelations, it is surely
>   beyond dispute that he is a liability who must be removed forthwith.’
>
> ‘Is the leader becoming a liability, or can he convince his critics
>   he's not a racist?’
>
> ‘He has been nothing but trouble since he moved in there in March, and
>   is a dangerous liability.’
>
> ‘I don't wish to blame my children for everything, but they are a
>   major liability when you're prone to blushing.’

All example sentences sourced from the link above, Oxford Living Dictionaries.